# Google Nearby discovering and advertising query

Tags: android, android-things, google-nearby

I've got an Android Things device which is advertising and an android device which is the discoverer. The connected works and is accepted on the phone, at which point I save the devices endpoint ID on both ends.

My question is that is it possible to connect to the devices after using just the endpoint ID? Or does my Android Things device *have* to advertise again and does the Android device *have* to discover again?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to advertise and discover again. The endpoint ID will also rotate.

Comment: What do you mean by rotate? Will it change? If so, how would I store previously authenticated devices by ID?

Comment: Yes, it will change each time you start advertising / scanning*. You can encode your own ID inside the endpoint name. eg. "1234:Will". And the other device will have to parse it out.

* It won't change immediately, but will change if you stop advertising / scanning for long enough.

Comment: Yes, endpoint name changes. If you want to authenticate devices, what you usually do is to use nearby to find out the IP and then connect using some rest API, which you can implement on Android things using nanohttpd